# ERR_TIMEOUT aws hosted zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

My domain is in google, I created a hosted zone in AWS and I have changed the name servers at google.

- ping to mydomain.app works
- curl to mydomain.app works
- host mydomain.app 8.8.8.8 works

I already have flushed my dns at chrome but my domain can't be reached at any browser nor device I have tried.

What could be do?

Comment: What are the security groups for the instance or load balancer that you use?

Answer (score 1):

It means your server is not serving at port 80 which is the HTTP port, you need to check the following:

1. Webserver is up and running and listening to 0.0.0.0 (all ports)

you can use the command :

```
netstat -anlp | grep 80
```

2. make sure your security group is allowing access to port 80 for all IP addresses
3. make sure the server firewall is disabled or allowing HTTP traffic

Comment: Try this and also noted down changed DNS across all ISP for HTTP or HTTPS protocol take 48 to 72 hours.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is no security group because I'm pointing to an s3 bucket with an alias (my bucket name and hostedzone and domain have the same name), the problem seem's to be that browser is redirecting to https and it doesn't exist, I am wondering if this is by aws configuration o all browser I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon S3 website endpoints do not support HTTPS. For information about using HTTPS with an Amazon S3 bucket.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/

You can use CloudFront.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-cloudfront-to-s3-origin.html